# ip addresses of the computers in VPN network

Tags: linux, vpn

I've established a VPN connection from my home computer to the network at my work. Is there a linux command that shows the ip addresses of the computers in this VPN network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to see OTHER computers on your network then nmap is probabyl going to be what you want. An example of how to use it is as follows:

```
nmap -sn 192.168.10.0/24
```

This will do a ping sweep and list all computers which respond to a ping on your network (assuming that the network is 192.168.10.*).

More information about nmap can be found here:

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/470979-who-and-what-is-on-my-network-probing-your-network-with-linux